# git how to fix directory with two file name identical under windows

Tags: windows, git, duplicates

We have a project which is used by dev under linux and also by dev under windows.
Now someone under linux created two files: file1.cpp and File1.cpp in the same directory.
they are identical, now when I checkout the branch under windows,  it automatically tells me that File1.cpp and file1.cpp have been modified.
How can I get rid of file1.cpp and keep File1.cpp ?

if it can be done from windows it would be best, because this problems only affect dev working under windows, and they do not have all access to a linux machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### TL;DR

While the OS is case insensitive, `git mv` is not and you can use it to fix the situation.

##### Details

I just reproduced your problem, and you can use the (case sensitive) `git mv` command to fix things on Windows.

I created a repo with files `foo` and `FOO` with different contents on a different machine. When I checked it out on Windows, it told me that `FOO` was modified but didn't say anything about `foo`. I would expect that in your case as well, only one should be flagged as modified if you did a fresh checkout.

Now, that means that `foo` was OK, but `FOO` was not. So I moved `foo` to a new name:

```
git mv foo foo-renamed
```

now git status is telling me `deleted: FOO` because the OS removed "both foo and FOO" since there was only one file there. So check it out again:

```
git checkout FOO
```

and now git status just says I renamed foo and FOO is fine.

Now the two files are distinct, you can use `git mv` again if you need, to get to the real names you want to keep in the end. Commit the results when you're happy with them.

##### Reference

I got my idea from https://www.hanselman.com/blog/git-is-casesensitive-and-your-filesystem-may-not-be-weird-folder-merging-on-windows although my solution is not quite identical and my write up is my own.